# SSDT: Whats the best way to deploy predefined data?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, deployment, sql-server-data-tools

Generally we want to deploy the database and populate some tables with predefined values (eg the Country and Product Category tables)

I saw this example using merge:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/02/02/including-data-in-an-sql-server-database-project.aspx

It seems a good solution but is there any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MERGE statements are best at the usual predefined case which is lookup tables, things like:

```
create table gender(
 gender_id int,
 gender_description varchar(6)
)
```

I would say for larger tables with alot of columns or data or where the unique key is not known up front then it isn't ideal, in this case you should write your own insert, update, delete statements etc.

In case you do decide to go with merge statements, this add in helps you by building the merge statements for you:

https://the.agilesql.club/Blog/Ed-Elliott/Introducing-MergeUi-Create-And-Edit-Merge-Statements